# Pytorch giving positional argument error while calling a method

Tags: python, pytorch

Pytorch code is giving an error of missing position argument, while I have already given x as an input argument.

**Code:**

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(8, 5)
        self.output = nn.Linear(5, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = 2*F.sigmoid(self.hidden(x))
        x = F.softmax(self.output(x), dim= 0)
        return x

x = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0] , dtype = torch.float32)
f = Network()
print(f(x))
```

> tensor([1.], grad_fn=)

```
Network.forward(x)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [98], in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 Network.forward(x)
>
> TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you executed? The error message says otherwise...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure just re-checked it! Kindly check the accepted answer and my reply! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Network.forward(x)` - in this line you are calling method using class, not instance. It requires 2 parameters in this case: `self` and `x`.
There is no need to call forward method directly.

The following lines perform forward call implicitly and it is a proper way of using it.

```
f = Network()
print(f(x))
```

**UPD**

```
f = Network()
network_output = f(x)  # <-- this will perform `forward` method indirectly
```

It is described here: [torch.nn.Module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.forward)

> Although the recipe for forward pass needs to be defined within this
> function, one should call the Module instance afterwards instead of
> this since the former takes care of running the registered hooks while
> the latter silently ignores them.

Instead of `f.forward(x)` you have to do just `f(x)`. Otherwise module functionality will be incomplete because you will not get any hooks registered for the given module. It is so for all modules in PyTorch. For example, you used `self.hidden(x)` in your code, not `self.hidden.forward(x)`.

Comment: Got it! I should've called f.forward(x) instead!

Comment: Btw, when I'm defining my class as nn.Module I didn't specify what all arguments will be required. Does that mean, nn.Module itself specifies the arguments which it needs , i.e a tensor (x) in this case?

Comment: You specified `x` as a positional argument in the header of `forward`, so it is required that you provide `x`. What is not clear for you? Btw, you **shouldn't** call `forward` but instead `__call__` (*i.e.* with parentheses `f(x)`) because PyTorch wraps the `forward` function with some required additional logic.

Comment: I did not understand the 2nd part of your answer. shall I call 'forward' as '__forward__' ? I tried using f.forward(x) and it worked! Can you please suggest me the topic which I should read in order to grasp this concept! Thanks!

Comment: @AnshumanSinha I updated my answer with a bit more explanation